# In Ktor, how can I stream an InputStream into a HttpClient Request's body?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I am using [Ktor 1.2.2](https://api.ktor.io/1.2.2/) and I have an InputStream object that I want to use as the body for an HttpClient request I make down the line. Up until Ktor 0.95 there was this [InputStreamContent](https://api.ktor.io/0.9.5/io.ktor.webjars/-input-stream-content/index.html) object that seemed to do just that but it has been removed from Ktor at version 1.0.0 (couldn't figure out why unfortunately).

I can make it work using a ByteArrayContent (see code below) but I'd rather find a solution that does not require loading the entire InputStream into memory...

```
ByteArrayContent(input.readAllBytes())
```

This code is a simple test case that emulate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
val file = File("c:\\tmp\\foo.pdf")
val inputStream = file.inputStream()
val client = HttpClient(CIO)
client.call(url) {
      method = HttpMethod.Post
      body = inputStream // TODO: Make this work :(
    }
// [... other code that uses the response below]
```

Let me know if I missed any relevant information,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only API (that I have found...) in Ktor 1.2.2  is potentially sending a multi-part request, which would require your receiving server to be able to handle this, but it does support a direct InputStream.

From their docs:

```
val data: List<PartData> = formData {
    // Can append: String, Number, ByteArray and Input.
    append("hello", "world")
    append("number", 10)
    append("ba", byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4))
    append("input", inputStream.asInput())
    // Allow to set headers to the part:
    append("hello", "world", headersOf("X-My-Header" to "MyValue"))
}
```

This being said, I don't know how it works internally and likely still loads to memory the entirety of the stream.

The readBytes method is buffered, so wont take up the entirety of memory.

```
inputStream.readBytes()
inputStream.close()
```

As a note, you are still required to close the inputStream with most methods on InputStreams

Ktor Source: https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/call/requests.html#the-submitform-and-submitformwithbinarydata-methods

Kotlin Source: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/index.html

Comment: Currently, `inputStream.asInput()` returns an implementation of `Input`, that seems to handle stream closing

Answer (score 5):

One way to achieve that is to create a subclass of [OutgoingContent.WriteChannelContent](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-http/io.ktor.http.content/-outgoing-content/index.html), and set it to the body of your post request.

An example could look like this:

```
class StreamContent(private val pdfFile:File): OutgoingContent.WriteChannelContent() {
    override suspend fun writeTo(channel: ByteWriteChannel) {
        pdfFile.inputStream().copyTo(channel, 1024)
    }
    override val contentType = ContentType.Application.Pdf
    override val contentLength: Long = pdfFile.length()
}


// in suspend function
val pdfFile = File("c:\\tmp\\foo.pdf")
val client = HttpClient()
val result = client.post<HttpResponse>("http://upload.url") {
    body = StreamContent(pdfFile)
}
```

Comment: @Peter and Stefan that saved my day. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me on Ktor 1.3.0 to upload files to GCP:

```
client.put<Unit> {
    url(url)
    method = HttpMethod.Put
    body = ByteArrayContent(file.readBytes(), ContentType.Application.OctetStream)
}
```

Comment: You are smart to read the whole thing in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to get the solution from @stefan to work. Here's my alternative example (targeting Ktor 2.2.2):

```kotlin
class StreamContent(private val pdfFile: File) : OutgoingContent.ReadChannelContent() {
    override fun readFrom(): ByteReadChannel = pdfFile.readChannel()
    override val contentType = ContentType.Application.Pdf
    override val contentLength: Long = pdfFile.length()
}

// in suspend function
val pdfFile = File("c:\\tmp\\foo.pdf")
val client = HttpClient()
val result = client.post<HttpResponse>("http://upload.url") {
    setBody(StreamContent(pdfFile))
}
```